# What happened to Section 31 after DS9?

Tags: star-trek, section-31

It would seem by the time of [Lower Decks](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Section_31#Later_legacy), Section 31 isn't a total secret anymore, so officially, what happened to Section 31? Did they dissolve it into Starfleet intelligence?

Comment: It doesn’t exist…..

Comment: At least 2 lesser TV series made it very uncool and unsecret and made them the bad guys.

Comment: I've seen theories that Kovich (https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kovich) might be a member of Section 31 but haven't seen anything to prove it one way or the other

Comment: We’ll get back to you on that.